# GeoServer's shared DB connection

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table "geometry_table" that has a 1-to-many relation to another table "properties_table", where each geometry has many properties. These properties hold style values of geoemtries (e.g color, stroke-width, ... etc).
I have a CSS style document that's used to style this geometry_table layer, something like the following:

```
/*Lines*/
[GetStyleProperty(geomId, 'visible') = 'true'] [dimension(geometry) = 1] [@sd < GetStyleProperty(geomId, 'feature_max_scale')] [@sd > GetStyleProperty(geomId, 'feature_min_scale')]{
   stroke: [GetStyleProperty(geomId, 'stroke_color')];
   stroke-width: [GetStyleProperty(geomId, 'stroke_width')];
   stroke-dasharray: [GetStyleProperty(geomId, 'stroke_dasharray')];
   stroke-opacity: [GetStyleProperty(geomId, 'opacity')];
}
```

The function "GetStyleProperty" is a custom Geotool function I've created to read a given property name of a given geometry from the DB. This function first opens a DB connection, then executes a DB stored function, then closes the connection.

My problem is that loading the geometry_table layer takes too much time (more than 6 seconds to display arround 10 featrues only). I have recognized that the problem is from my CSS Style document, because if I use another style document (e.g the generic one) the layer is dispalyed in less than one second. I've measured the execution time of "GetStyleProperty" function and found that quarter of the time is wasted in opening the DB connection.

So, my question is: instead of opening a DB connection in every function call, is there any shared connection that I can use to connect to my DB? Or, how can I make a shared DB connection that lives as long as the GeoServer application lives?

I'm using the following code to create a DB connection:

```
public static Connection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spatialdbnew";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "postgres", "postgres"); //use postgres username to skip row-level security to enhance performance

        /*
         * Add the geometry types to the connection.
         */
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conn).addDataType("geometry",
                (Class<? extends PGobject>) Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conn).addDataType("box3d",
                (Class<? extends PGobject>) Class.forName("org.postgis.PGbox3d"));

        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: why do you need a custom function, just use the attributes directly from a view

Comment: Hi Ian, I can't use a view, because the relation between the geometries table and the properties table is one-to-many, so if I create a view there will be many records for each feature (duplicate geometry data)

Comment: Please guide me if I'm missing something.

Comment: You could be using the JNDI connection, which contains a pool of connections. It is generally not a good idea to keep a connection open at all times, because you would need one connection for every thread (ex: 4 tiles requests in parallel, you don't want a single connection for the 4 requests). Using a connection from the pool should be fairly fast, as it doesn't have to always be re-established to the server ("closing" the connection means putting it back in the pool, which in turn decides to keep it open or to close it for real after some idle time)

Comment: Thanks JGH for your reply, but how to do that from the code (from a Geotools custom function)?

Comment: are you using a GeoTools datastore to access the tables?

Comment: maybe you can add the custom code

Comment: Hi Ian, question is updated.